# Strange methods asign variables

Tags: vbscript

Trying to understand other programers code

Please tell why it use this methods?

```
1. useradmin = user_Perms = "Admin" 'What it means and why it need asign "Admin" if user_Perms is already = "Admin"?
2. If 1=0 Then
3. If strText > 0 Then  ' How text string can be >0 ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBScript `=` is used for assignment **and** comparison. So `useradmin` will be assigned the boolean result of the comparison of the content of `user_Perms` vs. the string literal "Admin".

Evidence

```
>> For Each user_Perms In Split("User Admin")
>>     useradmin = user_Perms = "Admin"
>>     WScript.Echo user_Perms, TypeName(useradmin), CStr(useradmin)
>> Next
>>
User Boolean False
Admin Boolean True
```

---

`If 1=0 Then` is a slightly more convoluted way of writing `If False Then`. The code in the `Then` branch will never be executed.

---

As VBScript is weakly typed and does type conversions automagically, `strText > 0` may be True, False, or something you didn't intend:

```
>> strText = "5"
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(strText), CStr(strText > 0)
>> strText = 5
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(strText), CStr(strText > 0)
>> strText = "-1"
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(strText), CStr(strText > 0)
>>
String True
Integer True
String False
```

That's why you should always compare values of the same type.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much